# the probem Cors whene i send request from react to spring boot

Tags: spring

i have application spring boot back end and i add this in the AuthorizationFilter

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
```

whene i log in it works but whene i try to to exu=ecute an other request it send me this error:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/tasks' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

i dont know why there is no the problem of Cros in the authentication beacause it is the same domaine
please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Is the other request also authenticated?

Comment: the request authentication is working and it send  the jwt that i use to send an other request after authentication this request has this problem cros

Comment: And does this request goes through the `AuthorizationFilter`?

Comment: I think yes because the AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to handle and configure CORS globally in Spring Boot which should solve your problem:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    }
}
```

For more details please check [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors).